# dartdocgen: how to view docs locally

Tags: json, dart

I am having trouble using dartdocgen and dartdoc-viewer to pump my JSON files to the browser. I have had success getting all the JSON files from my application but haven't had any success actually viewing them in the browser. Based on my research, the best way to do this is hosting dartdoc-viewer on a local server as mentioned by this document:

https://www.dartlang.org/tools/dartdocgen/#deploy

However I just cannot seem to get it to work following these directions (I would like to approach it via dartium):

https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc-viewer/

I understand that once I am able to run pub build and compile to javascript that I dump the client/build folder into my server along with the docs folder under the URL, I am golden. That's where the issue is, how to get it from the docs folder to javascript to the browser.

I would like to be able to use dartdocgen to it's full potential so can I get some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just run `dartdocgen --serve .`

see https://www.dartlang.org/tools/dartdocgen/#view-locally

Is not what you are looking for?

Comment: Note that the dartdoc viewer does not currently work in Dartium. It forces the use of the shadow DOM polyfill, because it's using bootstrap styles, which don't work with shadow DOM. Dartium doesn't support the polyfill.